# Vue.js filter data by multiple filters on specific columns

Tags: filter, vue.js

In vue.js how can you filter a table using mutiple filters that target a specific column on the table.

For example if I have two search fields `name` and `age` how can I bind them to search the respective columns on the table below. So if user enters a name in the name input it should only search for a name on the name column. If the user enters an age as well then it should form an `and` condition and search for an age in the age column. Currently the filters simply search the entire table.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>The Vast World of Vue.js</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        </head>

        <body id="demo" class="container">

            <input v-model="name" class="form-control" placeholder="search by name"><br>

            <input v-model="age" class="form-control" placeholder="search by age">

            <table class="table table-striped">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th >
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th >
                            Age
                        </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="item in people | filterBy name | filterBy age">
                        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>

            <script>
               new Vue({

                        el: '#demo',

                        name: '',

                        age: '',

                        data: {

                            people: [
                                { name: 'John', age: 50 },
                                { name: 'Jane', age: 22 },
                                { name: 'Paul', age: 34 },
                                { name: 'Kate', age: 15 },
                            ]
                        }

                    });


            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Vue 2

Since we don't have filters anymore, you'd need to use a computed property.

So you can do something like:

```
{
  data: {
    people: [{ name: }],
    age: 28,
    name: 'bi',
  }
  computed: {
    filteredPeople () {
      const { name, age, people } = this
      return this.people
        .filter(person => person.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        .filter(person => person.age === age)
    },
  },
}
```

Then you'd loop through `filteredPeople` instead of `people`

```
<tr v-for="person in filteredPeople">...</tr>
```

### Vue 1

If you take a look at the second example in API documentation for [`filterBy`](http://vuejs.org/api/#filterBy) you'll see the ability to limit it to a field.

You'd want something like:

```
item in people | filterBy name in 'name' | filterBy age in 'age'
```

Comment: What about if you're trying to make it an OR condition? Like if the people were in groups, and the user was selecting 2 or more groups, and you wanted to match all the people in either group?

Comment: You would need to (and should) use a computed property for that.

Comment: this is very useful.  thank you.  man i miss V1 filters though... why did they ever remove them?

Comment: @WhiteRau, Evan You argued that while the built in filters could be usefull, it is better to allow the developer to program them themselves so as to not bloat their codebase with dead code